# Scala null pointer exception cause by .toString on a variable which is not null

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception

Can anyone please explain the following behavior in scala?

Basically in the following piece of code, if you do `getOptionValue[Int](None)`, it returns 0 but when you do `getOptionValue[Int](None).toString` it causes a null pointer exception.

Shouldn't the outcome be 0 cast into a string (ie. "0")?

PS: I am using scala 2.12.10

```scala
scala> def getOptionValue[T](option: Option[T]): T = {
     |     if (option.isEmpty) {
     |       null.asInstanceOf[T]
     |     } else
     |       option.get
     |   }
getOptionValue: [T](option: Option[T])T

scala> getOptionValue[Int](None)
res35: Int = 0

scala> res35.toString
res36: String = 0

scala> getOptionValue[Int](None).toString
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 47 elided
```

Also the below works just fine

```scala
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int]
res0: Int = 0

scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int].toString
res1: String = 0
```

Comment: Don't do that anyway! Use `.orNull` of really you need null in your code but it should only ever happen when calling Java code at the last moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These:

```
null.asInstanceOf[Int]
null.asInstanceOf[Int].toString // "0"
```

are rather (unreliable) exceptions.

On JVM calling any method on `null` reference ends up with `NullPointerException`.

Scala doesn't treat `scala.Int` always as `java.lang.Integer` (which can be nullable) nor it always treat it as `int` (primitive, non-nullable by design) - it uses either representation based on context.

In case of `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` Scala will actually perform a conversion rather than casting, which is why you'll get `0`. But it can only perform this casting when it knows the cast type (`Null`) and the target type (`Int`), as after the type-erasure it doesn't do such tricks.

Which is why when you are using generics, Scala will only know that there is `null` cast to some reference type `T`, method definition doesn't know anything about `T` being `Int`, so it won't perform conversion, it will still be `null` returned from the method, and then it will throw NPE on `.toString`.

The reason these exceptions exist in the first place is that it probably felt bad that when you have case like:

```
val a: Int = null.asInstanceOf[Int]
```

compiler would most likely use `int`, casting wouldn't make sense, so they opted for conversion so that primitive would get the value `0` rather than compile or runtime error. But this can only be done when you know that you are targeting something that can be a primitive type (`Int`, `Double`, `Char`, ...).